# Join unrelated models and delete duplicate from the queryset

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm, django-database

I really need help here. I have the two tables below. As you can see they are completely independent (No relationship between the two).

class People(models.Model):

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35) 
phone_number = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=15)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

class Blacklist(models.Model):

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35) 
phone_number = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
```

How do I proceed to accomplish below : 
* I have a list of phone numbers from "Blacklist" table.

1. I want to be able to check if "phone_number(s)" field from table "People" is identical to any "phone_number" in "Blacklist".
2. If it is identical, DELETE duplicate "phone_number" from "People" table.
   I have spent a few days and have not found the correct way to do it.

I am using PostgreSQL database.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Blacklist model, you can simply add blacklisted as a boolean field to the People model, which will be false by default

```
class People(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35) 
    phone_number = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=15)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    is_blacklisted = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

If you have a People object you can just check if he is blacklisted with an if statement

```
if mypeople.is_blacklisted:
    mypeople.delete()
```

You can also get People who are / are not blacklisted with a filter

```
blacklisted_people = People.objects.filter(is_blacklisted = True)
non_blacklisted_people = People.objects.filter(is_blacklisted = False)
```

Comment: I updated my answer, you can just call delete() on the object if it's blacklisted and it will be removed

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you @AmineMessaoudi